# TypeScript AuthContext cant take undefined when on Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, authentication, use-context

I'm using TypeScript and I need to create a route with the user info and sign with google from firebase (I plan to switch to Redux as an exercise later).

Happens that when typing the user, if its logged in = User, if its not = undefined, but Router won't take an undefined as a child...

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import { auth, firebase } from "./services/firebase";

import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { NewRoom } from "./pages/NewRoom";

type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  avatar: string;
};

type AuthContextType = {
  user: User | undefined;
  signInWithGoogle: () => Promise<void>;
};

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextType);

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();

  async function signInWithGoogle() {
    // provider is whos giving the log in - google
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    const result = await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

    if (result.user) {
      // username, photoLocation, uniqueID
      const { displayName, photoURL, uid } = result.user;

      // what if theres no data?
      if (!displayName || !photoURL)
        throw new Error("Missing information from Google Account");

      // set user information
      setUser({
        id: uid,
        name: displayName,
        avatar: photoURL,
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signInWithGoogle }}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/room/new" element={<NewRoom />} />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you specifically point out where the error happens?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza  `AuthContext.Provider value={{ user (null when user is not logged in}}` so Routes doesn't like it when is null and throws an error saying its child can't be null, but what other way can I say the user is not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to render nothing, use `null` instead of `undefined`. If User is not not logged in, you can redirect to an unauthorized page using `<Navigate to="/signin" />` which is a valid child for router (just a suggestion).

Comment: `Compiled with problems:

ERROR in src/App.tsx:51:40

TS2322: Type 'User | undefined' is not assignable to type 'User | null'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'User | null'.
    49 |     <BrowserRouter>
    50 |       <Routes>
  > 51 |         <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signInWithGoogle }}>
       |                                        ^^^^
    52 |           <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    53 |           <Route path="/room/new" element={<NewRoom />} />
    54 |         </AuthContext.Provider>`

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have `User | undefined` union type assigned. If you are using VS Code try searching `User | undefined` in search section and replace `User | undefined` with `User | null`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was late and past my bed time, it was a simple fix:

before:
`return (

```
  <Routes>
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signInWithGoogle }}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/room/new" element={<NewRoom />} />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

after:

``
return (

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, signInWithGoogle }}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/room/new" element={<NewRoom />} />
    </Routes>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

);
``

Just move AuthContext out of Routes as it is not a Route, obviously